# How do I name an audio track with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

When a file has more audio tracks, VLC can show their names - or titles, I am not sure about the terminology - in menu under Audio>Audio Track.

When I recode the file with

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2  -c:v libx264 -preset slow -profile:v high -crf 17  -c:a copy output.mp4
```

The names get lost and only generic "Track 1" and "Track 2" appear. How do I keep it? Or how do I set a custom name.

The output of the command is like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i Shades_of_winter_24FPS_x264_5.1_AC3+R128.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2  -vf "ass=p.ass"  -c:v libx264 -preset slow -profile:v high -crf 17  -c:a copy -metadata:s:a:0:0 -language="ble" -metadata:s:a:1 language="bli" -metadata:s:a:0:2 title="bla"  -t 6 a.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.3.git-1ace957 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 26 2014 20:25:06 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab --enable-libpulse --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      52. 92.101 / 52. 92.101
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 49.100 / 55. 49.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.102 /  4. 11.102
  libavresample   1.  3.  0 /  1.  3.  0
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Shades_of_winter_24FPS_x264_5.1_AC3+R128.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2014-10-04 00:16:47
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.9 2013051800
  Duration: 00:51:22.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 19802 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 18780 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-10-04 00:16:47
      encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 640 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-10-04 00:16:47
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 197 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-10-12 23:08:29
File 'a.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 0x1a682a0] Added subtitle file: 'p.ass' (7 styles, 9 events)
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] profile High, level 5.0
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=umh subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=50 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=17.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mp4 @ 0x1a86a20] track 1: codec frame size is not set
Output #0, mp4, to 'a.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    encoder         : Lavf55.49.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-10-04 00:16:47
      encoder         : Lavc55.69.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: ac3 ([165][0][0][0] / 0x00A5), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), 640 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-10-04 00:16:47
      -language       : ble
      title           : bla
    Stream #0:2(bli): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, 197 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-10-12 23:08:29
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 0x1a682a0] Neither PlayResX nor PlayResY defined. Assuming 384x288
frame=  144 fps= 79 q=-1.0 Lsize=     651kB time=00:00:06.01 bitrate= 886.3kbits/s    
video:122kB audio:522kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.122499%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] frame I:1     Avg QP: 2.17  size:  7785
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] frame P:48    Avg QP:11.31  size:  2128
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] frame B:95    Avg QP:11.73  size:   151
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] consecutive B-frames: 11.1%  1.4%  4.2% 83.3%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] mb I  I16..4: 99.1%  0.0%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.2%  P16..4:  1.1%  0.2%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:98.1%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.5%  L0:51.3% L1:43.9% BI: 4.8%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] 8x8 transform intra:4.3% inter:28.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] direct mvs  spatial:92.6% temporal:7.4%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 5.4% 2.2% 2.2% inter: 0.2% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 97%  1%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  2%  3% 94%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36% 15% 19%  4%  6%  5%  5%  4%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 98%  0%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:39.6% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] ref P L0: 72.3%  8.1% 14.8%  2.8%  1.6%  0.3%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] ref B L0: 58.4% 29.7%  8.5%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] ref B L1: 95.3%  4.7%
[libx264 @ 0x1a87be0] kb/s:165.74
```

Comment: Have you seen any other kind? e.g. "surround track"? Or are you referring to the language option?

Comment: Yeah, one is "Surround" and the other is "R128 Stereo"

Comment: It appears that ffmpeg doesn't write the metadata/disposition in the format that VLC looks for:
http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2019-July/044936.html

From Moritz Barsnick:
`"In ffmpeg's libavformat/mpegts.c (demuxer), both the ISO 639 language
descriptor and the supplementary audio descriptor are evaluated to
obtain the disposition information. In the ffmpeg muxer, only the ISO
639 language descriptor is written though. VLC on the other hand only
checks the supplementary audio descriptor. Nice mismatch. ;-)"`

Answer (score 43):

You can apply metadata to particular streams. This example will add `title` and `language` metadata to audio streams/tracks 1 & 2 (note `ffmpeg` starts counting from 0).

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -metadata:s:a:0 title="One" -metadata:s:a:1 title="Two" -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 language=spa output.mp4
```

- `-map 0` selects all streams from `input.mp4`, otherwise default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior chooses only 1 stream per stream type.
- `-c copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode to avoid re-encoding.
- `-metadata:s:a:0 title="One"` sets title `One` to audio 0.
- `-metadata:s:a:1 title="Two"` sets title `Two` to audio 1.
- `-metadata:s:a:0 language=eng` sets English language for audio 0.
- `-metadata:s:a:1 language=spa` sets Spanish language for audio 1.

For more info look for `-metadata` and `-map_metadata` in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).

Comment: Thanks, but this command does not produce anything that vlc recognizes (it plays it, but does not display the titles under Audio>Audio Track ). But your answer helped me to understand ffmpeg syntax better:-).

Comment: @sup Strange. It works for me. Is your VLC ancient?

Comment: Indeed, strange. No, both ffmpeg (2.3.git-1ace957) and VLC (2.3.git-1ace957) are fairly new - I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I have started a thread about it on ffmpeg-user: https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2014-November/024080.html and it seems the issue is complicated because of compatibilities between different applications.

Comment: MPC-HC seems to ignore `title` but does display `handler_name` as though it were a title. Worth a shot to see if it works for VLC, too. (note that the ffmpeg command line should set `handler`, not `handler_name`).

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm except that I had to use "language" instead of "lang" to set the language metadata.

Comment: @Zoltan You are correct. Unfortunately that's not the first time I've made that same typo... I'll fix it (again).

Comment: What does `s` do in `metadata:s:a:0`? I know `a` means audio, and `0` means first stream. But I don't know about `s`.

Comment: @Shayan It means "stream" for steam level metadata. Others are `g`lobal (container), `c`hapter, and `p`rogram. See `-metadata` and `-map_metadata` options in the [`ffmpeg` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).

Comment: I think this misses an example command how to add an audio track while at the same time specifying its language (maybe edit the answer to add such). The following is an example that specifies German for the default audio track (the video's only audio channel) and English for the audio track that is added anew: `ffmpeg -i "/dir/video.mkv" -i "/dir2/audio.ac3" -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest -metadata:s:a:0 language=ger -metadata:s:a:0 title="GER" -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 title="ENG" "/dir/output.mkv"`