# How to read the name of audio track using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I was able to create MP4 with multiple audio tracks and custom name for each track using this example [How do I name an audio track with ffmpeg - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/834244/how-do-i-name-an-audio-track-with-ffmpeg).

Now I want to read the titles back programmatically. How to do this using ffmpeg?

I checked that the data is stored in the MP4 using VLC

Comment: `ffprobe -show_format -show_streams -i input.mp4` max info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffprobe` doesn't seem to recognize the title metadata for streams, but you can use `mediainfo` in this case.

```
mediainfo --Output="Audio;%Title%" input.mp4
```

If the input has multiple audio streams you can add arbitrary text for easier parsing:

```
mediainfo --Output="Audio;Audio Title: %Title%\n" output.mp4
```

Example output:

```
Audio Title: foo
Audio Title: bar
```

- `mediainfo --Info-Parameters` provides a list of available parameters.
- `mediainfo --Output-Help` has more info and examples for the `--Output` option.

Comment: Is the same limitation as ffprobe true for ffmpeg?

Comment: @R.D Yes, appears to be true.

Comment: it seems ffprobe can also do it. Please see comment above. Need to try

Comment: @R.D I already tried that when I made the answer, but no title was reported. Did you try? Did it work for you? You can make a test file: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i sine -map 0 -map 0 -metadata:s:a:0 title="foo" -metadata:s:a:1 title="bar" -t 1 output.mp4`

Comment: @R.D Let me clarify that ffprobe will display the global title metadata, and that's what I assume the comment was assuming you wanted, but your question is asking about per-stream title metadata.

Comment: ah, got it. Thanks for clarifying.